# SWReveal with a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swrevealviewcontroller, uibuttonbaritem

So I wanted to add a slide menu to my app where if you tap a button, the menu slides from the left. After some research I found a guide for using SWRevealViewController to create a slide out menu, but I quickly realized that video, and pretty much every other guide for SWReveal, uses a `UIBarButtonItem` for the button that you tap to reveal the menu. So what I need help with is figuring out how to do what the guide says to do for the `UIBarButtonItem`, but for a `UIButton` instead.

Let's say there is a `UIBarButtonItem` called OpenSideBar. The guide says to do this in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
OpenSideBar.target = self.revealViewController()
OpenSideBar.action = Selector("revealToggle")
```

So I'm not exactly sure what that does but I need to find a way to do it for a `UIButton`. An explanation for what it does would also be appreciated because the guy in the video didn't do much explaining.

The button is currently an outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var OpenSideBar: UIButton!
```

but please specify if I should recreate it as an action instead and do stuff in the function instead of the `viewDidLoad` method.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. The SWViewController.h file can be found on github at this link:

https://github.com/PCmex/lift-side-memu-in-swift-3/blob/master/memuDemo/SWRevealViewController.h

and SWViewController.m at this link:

https://github.com/PCmex/lift-side-memu-in-swift-3/blob/master/memuDemo/SWRevealViewController.m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `OpenSideBar.target = self.revealViewController()` sets the target for your `UIBarButtonItem` and the line `OpenSideBar.action = Selector("revealToggle")` sets the action that needs to be performed upon tapping the said button.

You can achieve this functionality using `UIButton` in one of two ways.
You can either set the target action for a `UIButton` just like you would for a `UIBarButtonItem. The only difference is that they both have a different syntax. You would be doing it like this

```
OpenSideBar.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

or you can hookup your `@IBAction` and in your method, use

```
self.revealViewController().revealToggle(self)
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't have any errors prior to running it anymore but now I have a runtime error that says "-[LE.MapViewController OpenSideBar:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance " followed by a bunch of random letters and numbers that I'm guessing is a memory location. Any idea why? I used the first version that doesn't require hooking up the `@IBAction` because hooking it up was giving me errors when I tried to add it to a subview.

Comment: I'll have to look at the class to pin point to problematic piece of code. You'll have to edit the question with additional information.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out it was just that the storyboard button was still linked to an @IBAction method.